# Inequality prove or disprove.

Tags: calculus, inequality

Okay so I am looking for some proof for:
$$\left|\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}\right| \le 1 : \forall x \in [-1,1].$$ 
The proof has to be based and not to claim some thing like "one can easily see that the maximum value is at ... and the minimum is ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(1-x)^2 \geq 0$ $(1+x)^2 \geq 0$  we have
$$1-2x+x^2 \geq 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad 1+2x+x^2 \geq 0$$
that is 
$$-2x \leq 1+x^2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad 2x\leq 1+x^2.$$
This is equal to
$$|2x| \leq 1+x^2$$
and gives
$$\left| \frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2} \right|=\frac{\left| 2x \right| }{ (1+x^2)^2  }  \leq \frac{1+x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \leq 1$$
where we used $x^2 \geq 0$ in the last inequality.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first 2 sentences ?looks like you made some big non based skip but maybe I'm missing some thing.

Comment: @Itay.V Sure, I edited my answer!

Comment: Is there a way to show that it lesser and not lesser equal ?

Comment: Never mind, got it!

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=\tan\theta$. we have
$$\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\tan^2\theta}=\sin 2\theta\cdot \cos^2 \theta$$
thus
$$\left| \frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2} \right|=\left|\sin 2\theta\cdot \cos^2 \theta\right|< 1$$

Comment: $$|sin 2a .cos^2a|=\\|sin 2a .\frac{(1+cos2a)}{2}|=\\\frac{1}{2}|sin2a +sin2a .cos 2a|=\\
\frac{1}{2}|sin2a +\frac{1}{2}sin4a |\\
 \leq\frac{1}{2}|sin2a| +\frac{1}{4}|sin4a | \\ \leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} <1$$